# unfortunately application has stopped Xamarin C# Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, logcat

Using Windows 10, Visual Studio with Xamarin C# Android.

Getting "couldn't connect to logcat get process id returned 0" and "unfortunately application has stopped."

How can i resolve this? Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2hrV.jpg

Comment: Looks like you are using Shared runtime and Xamarin.Android api 22 doesn't exist on simulator. Try to change it in project properties.

Comment: I'm using API 19 and VS Emulator 7" Kitkat (4.4-Supported by API 19)

Comment: In project properties you have option "Use shared mono runtime" try to uncheck that.

Comment: In project properties you have option to "Use shared mono runtime". Try to uncheck that.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Your Android "Project Properties"in Visual Studio.
In "Android Option" **uncheck "Use Shared Runtime"** from "packaging".
It will deploy application as well run application on your device.