# C# XAMARIN Android apk installation problems

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, apk

I created small app in xamarin and I have a problem with install .apk file from my mobile application for Adroid.

When i installed .apk on my android device fist time i don't have any problems. Application ilstalled correctly and also works correctly. But when i make changes in project then archive it again and repeat steps to make .apk file it won't install on android device. Message on android is: "instalator was stopped".

Maybe i should change something in .android properties? I have no idea why it won't work

Comment: try deleting the old version from your device first

Comment: i've done it and unfortunately it wont work also

Comment: try to go to settings, apps, find your app and in the three dots on the right corner and select uninstall for all users otherwise check the packages for every user using adb shell commands and uninstall your old package

Comment: Did it have the same error message after uninstalling? @Koza12

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808253/unfortunately-application-has-stopped-xamarin-c-sharp-android 

Make sure to the same keystore file for archiving your apk.